# Access a variable in an array of classes within a class JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

Hi there I have a JNI question, I have the classes bellow.  I set the variables a,b,c and d in the class UserConfig in user space.

```
public class SetConfig extends Config {
    int status;

    public native int setConfig_IOCTL();

}

public class Config {
    public Config() { User = new UserConfig[100]; }

    int number;

    UserConfig[] user;
}

public class UserConfig {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}
```

I then want to assign the variables to a c struct that is then passed into a kernel driver.

```
typedef struct {
     int status;
     Config_t config;
} getConfig;

typedef struct {
    int number;
    UserConfig_t userConfig[100];
} Config_t;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} UserConfig_t;
```

I am having problems getting the fieldId to correctly access the fields within the UserConfig class and was looking for some help to point me in the correct direction.

I have this which I know is wrong.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL com_example_test_Config_config_IOCTL(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

     getConfig_t tempConfig;   

     jclass thisClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, instance);
     jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, thisClass, "a", "[LTest/jni/UserConfig;");
     tempConfig.config.userConfig[0] = (*env)->GetIntField(instance, fid);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have only started using JNI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C function's name associates it with a method `com.example.test.Config.config_IOCTL()`, but your actual native method is `<some_package>.SetConfig.setConfig_IOCTL()`.  Neither the class names nor the method names match.  You can use the `javah` utility to generate appropriate C declarations corresponding to the native method declarations in your Java classes.

Having properly matched the C function declaration to the Java native method declaration, you're going to need the native method (as it is presently declared) to do the following:

- Get the `jclass` of the object on which the method is invoked, as you already do.
- Retrieve a `jobjectarray` corresponding to the `user` field of that object (a `UserConfig[]`)
- Retrieve the desired element (which?) of the array via `GetObjectArrayElement()`
- Find the fieldIds of the wanted fields of *that object*s' class
- use those fieldIDs to retrieve the values of the fields

Overall, that's pretty messy.  It generally works out better to do as much as you can on the Java side, to make the JNI side easier to write.  For example, you might do something this instead (inferring a bit about the wanted semantics):

```
public class SetConfig extends Config {
    int status;

    public int setConfig_IOCTL() {
        return setConfig_IOCTL(user[number].a, user[number].b, user[number].c,
                user[number].d);
    }

    private native int setConfig_IOCTL(int a, int b, int c, int d);
}
```

I'm sure you can see how that minimizes the the work of the native method implementation, and minimizes the number of JNI functions it needs to call (possibly to zero).  Of course, the corresponding native implementation would have a different signature than your present one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code I have there is example code and not what I have implemented.  I shall try your suggestion thanks.